# Why OpenFlow allows L4 features to be included in match structure

Tags: cisco, routing, ethernet, sdn, openflow

So in simple scenario, a router needs to maintain a routing table that has at least minimum routing features such as `Destination IP`, `Next Hub`, and `NIC interface`. However, in OpenFlow specification the switch can match the received packet against plenty of features even from L4 such as `TCP dest_port` and `TCP src_port`, or from L2 such as `src_MAC` and `dest_MAC`. So why does OpenFlow add features from L4 and L2 in the [matching structure](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-MatchStructure) when we only need L3 information for routing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  because merely routing isn't enough.

In modern enterprise or service provider networks, there is usually a requirement to treat certain types of traffic differently than others.  For example, real-time traffic such as voice or video often requires a minimum amount of delay.  Other traffic may require a minimum amount of bandwidth.  Certain types of traffic may be directed to load balancers, reverse proxies, or policy enforcement points to be inspected or filtered.

One common way to distinguish different types of traffic is by layer 4 information (i.e. port numbers).  That's why it is included in the specification.